# Django ChoiceField and RadioSelect return EnumMeta error

Tags: python, django

I have a ChoiceField that I would like to show as Radio selection but I get the following error:

> EnumMeta.**call**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'

Here it is the code

model.py

```
class Answer(models.IntegerChoices):
    NO = 0, _('No')
    YES = 1, _('Yes')
```

form.py

```
    question = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=Answer,
        widget=forms.RadioSelect()
    )
```

I've followed the django documentation and I can't figure it out the nature of the error, thank you for any explanation that you can give me

Comment: `choices=Answer.choices`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not pass an `IntegerChoices` class as `choices=…` parameter. However an `IntegerChoices` class makes it more convenient to define choices, you can use the `.choices` attribute so:

```
question = forms.ChoiceField(
    choices=Answer.choices,
    widget=forms.RadioSelect()
)
```